# pst-optexp Drawbeam Error - GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Tags: pst-optexp

I have a problem with my pst-optexp package LaTeX script:

I can't draw two or more different beams, each one alone works fine, so the error lies in the \drawbeam command.

Here an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% general
\usepackage{nicefrac}

% for drawing the setup
\usepackage{pst-optexp}

\begin{document}

    \section{Main Section 1}
    \subsection{Test2}

    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(15.2,8.2)
        %Illumination
        \pnode(1.5,1){A}
        \pnode(7,1){B}
        \pnode(10,2){C}
        \pnode(4,2){D}
        \pnode(4,5){E}
        \pnode(10,5){F}
        \pnode(8.5,1){B1}

        \optbox[position=start, innerlabel](A)(B) {Laser1}
        \optbox[position=end, innerlabel](A)(B) {Fiber in}
        \optbox[position=start, innerlabel](C)(D) {Fiber out}
        \optbox[position=end, innerlabel](E)(F) {testbox}
        \mirror(D)(E)(F)
        \mirror(C)(D)(E)
        \drawbeam[linecolor=red, ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsidePos=0.4, arrowscale=1.3](C){6}{5}(F)
        \drawbeam[linecolor=green, ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsidePos=0.4, arrowscale=1.3](A)(B)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

If both drawbeams are enabled (like in the example), then the only the first one is drawn, and the second one not. This is the notification:

> Process started: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode
> "document".tex
>
> GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
>
> Process finished normally

I am using TexStudio and XeLaTeX, if any more information is needded, just let me know. Thanks

Comment: I have no error message with xexlatex, but the  green beam is missing.  However, it I compile via latex+dvips, it is fine, but I have to convert the .ps file to .pdf from gsview.

Comment: `pst-optexp` doesn't work properly with XeLaTeX.